# when i use ionicon ,i get the different icon

Tags: android, ionic-framework

This thing is amazing
first of all, I make a ionic project and then i link `ionic.min.css` and `ionic.bundle.js`
and use the ionicon in `app.html`, like this [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1ZP9.jpg)

but when i open it in the browser, i didnt get the expected result, it show like this [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlSHH.jpg)

finally i find it, **the *ionicons.ttf* is error**, when i download from the ionic website, and cover the Automatically generated ionicons.ttf, it work, but when i command
`ionic cordova build android`, it will rebuild a ionicons.ttf file and cover mine, it error again,
although i know the reason，but i can't repair, thanks for any answer.

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: `  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ionic.min.css">
  <script src="js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app2.js"></script>`

Comment: <ion-side-menus>
  <!-- content -->
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-icon ios="logo-apple" md="logo-android"></ion-icon>

    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">
      <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-information">
      </ion-tab>
      <ion-tab title="Contact" icon="ion-ios-world">
      </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>

Comment: juse a practice for me, the code structure is very simple

Comment: check my updated answer and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
<ion-tab tabIcon="home" tabTitle="Home"></ion-tab>
```

instead of `<ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home">`

Comment: OK,let me try it

Comment: what version of ionic are you using?

Comment: the ionic version is 3.5.0,I install the latest version yesterday

Comment: what are you trying to do? your code shows you're trying to use ion-tabs inside ion-side-menus. that's not the right way to do something i guess

Comment: I want to use ion-tabs as my footer,Delete other code useless

Comment: At first i have a left-side page when left sliding,so i use ion-side-menus

Comment: Because i build a ionic-v2 project, and  use ionic-v1 way to write,so it may has some differences, sorry for your time and thanks a lot.